# On iPhone, how do I check once per day to see if i should phone-home?

Tags: iphone, cron, nsfilemanager

I want to check a file on the server only once each day (NSURL).  And, no matter if I fetch the file or not, I do not run the function (to check for the file) again that day.

This would SEEM easy... but I forsee issues.  Say I had created a directory under the mainBundle: "/Library/runOnceEachDay/".  Perhaps I could write to /Library/runOnceEachDay/20100601 knowing that file would only exist if I already ran the function.  If it does not exist, run the function and after the function is successful write a zero length file with the date as the filename. Then check before running that function for "mainBundle/Library/runOnceEachDay/YYYYMMDD" whereas YYYYMMDD is today's date.  If that file exists, do not run.

I could run a housecleaning routine to clean that directory once/week or something.  Any better ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start the app, get the previous phone home date/time (NSDate) from NSUserDefaults.  (It won't be there the first time).  This [SO question (option 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013850/whats-the-optimum-way-of-storing-an-nsdate-in-nsuserdefaults) demonstrates how.

If more than 24 hours (or 7 days or whatever) has elapsed since that previous date/time (or you didn't find it there) then phone home and save the current date/time in NSUserDefaults for next startup.

Answer (score 4):

The logic is good. You could either do it with files as you say and "Documents" folder is a good location for such files, or you could just have a NSUserDefaults key with the date when you last phoned home.

Comment: Isn't Documents BAD as it would be open to viewing by users with the new "drop box" permissions of iTunes -- but thx for responding so quickly.