# how to find the expiry of the document in iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsdate, nsuserdefaults, nsfilemanager

Im looking for expiry of the document in iphone/ipad for my application,i want one of the document in the application to be removed from the device(application directory of iphone/ipad) after particular time period!!
Can any one get me the solution for that!!

Comment: I am assuming you are talking days, not minutes, since you make no mention of the document being stored on the device while the app is running, e.g. through a server download or user interaction. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your "best before"-date in NSUserDefaults. Check current date against "best before" when you start up the app. Delete your document if your best before date has passed.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

if([currentDate laterDate:bestBeforeDate] == currentDate) {
 //delete file
 NSError *error;
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:YOURPATH error:&error];
}
```

For a solution for storing your date in the defaults, [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013850/whats-the-optimum-way-of-storing-an-nsdate-in-nsuserdefaults).