# how to retrieve the date and time the application was closed in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datetime

I am working with one application where i need to display the date and time the application was closed lastly.It is possible to store and retrieve the date and time the iphone application was opened and closed? I am having one webservice that would store the date and time but i am not having idea about how to retrieve this thing.

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UIApplicationDelegate's methods:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

If you want to store date you probably want to use NSUserDefaults. It is really very straightforward. Check docs.

Here is another link to help: [What's the optimum way of storing an NSDate in NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013850/whats-the-optimum-way-of-storing-an-nsdate-in-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: and use [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] to get the floating point timestamp of that time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in app delegate's function

`- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application ;`
 

or

`- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application ;`


To get date and time (hours and seconds also)

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSString *formattime=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSArray *chunks = [formattime componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSArray *sec = [[chunks objectAtIndex:2] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    //if([[sec objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"PM"]){
    int hour=[[chunks objectAtIndex:0]  intValue];
    int min= [[chunks objectAtIndex:1]  intValue];
    //pmoram=[sec objectAtIndex:1];
    int second=[[sec objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    //Use the date and release the dateFormatter
    [dateFormatter release];
```