# How to overwrite NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, nsuserdefaults, uilocalnotification

I have uilocalnotification where i am setting different time for each notification using NSDateComponents depending upon the number of times a item should get notifiied .

```
     -(NSArray *)fireDatesForFrequency:(int)freq
    {

        if (freq == 1)
        {

            [components setHour:8];
            [components setMinute:00];

            NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

            NSArray *dates =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:date, nil];

            return dates;
        }

        if (freq == 2) {

            [components setHour:8];
            [components setMinute:00];


            NSDate *date1 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

            [components setHour:20];
            [components setMinute:00];

            NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

            NSArray *dates =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:date1,date2, nil];

            return dates;
        }

        if (freq == 3)
        {

            [components setHour:8];
            [components setMinute:00];

            NSDate *date1 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

            [components setHour:12];
            [components setMinute:00];

            NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

            [components setHour:16];
            [components setMinute:00];

            NSDate *date3 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

            NSArray *dates =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:date1,date2,date3, nil];

            return dates;

        }


        if (freq == 4)
        {

            [components setHour:8];
            [components setMinute:00];

            NSDate *date1 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

            [components setHour:12];
            [components setMinute:00];

            NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

            [components setHour:16];
            [components setMinute:00];

            NSDate *date3 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

            [components setHour:20];
            [components setMinute:00];

            NSDate *date4 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

            NSArray *dates =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:date1,date2,date3,date4, nil];

            return dates;

        }

          return nil;

    }
```

Now i want to store these time in NSUserDefaults so that if a user wants to change the time depending upon his needs i want to store those time in NSUserdefaults . i want to replace default NSuserdefaults with userupdatednsuserdefaults ..There is segmented control with datepicker so when user selects time from datepicker that time should get updated to default nsuserdefaults .So if userselects first segmented controlitem that value should get stored in

```
- (IBAction)didChangeSegmentControl:(UISegmentedControl *)control
{
    NSInteger index = [notificationSessionTab selectedSegmentIndex];

    if (index == 0)
    {
        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];
        [components setHour:7];;
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date1 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:9];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        //NSArray *dates =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:date1,date2,date3,date4, nil];
        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:date1];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:date2];
        NSDate *selectedTime =[userTimePicker date];
    }

    if (index == 1)
    {
        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];

        [components setHour:11];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date1 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:13];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        //NSArray *dates =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:date1,date2,date3,date4, nil];
        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:date1];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:date2];
        NSDate *selectedTime =[userTimePicker date];
    }

    if (index == 2)
    {
        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];

        [components setHour:15];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date1 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:18];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        //NSArray *dates =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:date1,date2,date3,date4, nil];
        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:date1];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:date2];
        NSDate *selectedTime =[userTimePicker date];
    }

    if (index == 3)
    {
        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];

        [components setHour:19];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date1 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:21];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        //NSArray *dates =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:date1,date2,date3,date4, nil];
        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:date1];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:date2];
        NSDate *selectedTime =[userTimePicker date];
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you simplify your question? It seems that all of this code is potentially not the point. If all you want is to store a datetime in NSUserDefaults, store it using its timeIntervalSince1970.

Answer (score 0):

You can store NSDate in NSUserDefaults without it's overriding.
This question discussed more detailed here [What's the optimum way of storing an NSDate in NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013850/whats-the-optimum-way-of-storing-an-nsdate-in-nsuserdefaults).

You also can store in NSUserDefault array of dates. So I don't think that overriding standard UserDefaults is good idea, instead you can create Category extension to achieve more abstraction.

Comment: i just want to replace default date1 with user picked time ..if user didnt pick new time then in default time notification should show up..

Comment: As i understand, you need not only to replace saved values in userDefaults, but also change fire date of currently scheduling local notifications?

Comment: i guess you should cancel started notifications, and recreate them with new fire dates