# NSUserDefaults different value when return to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsusernotification

I save a value in `NSUserDefaults` when I put my app in background mode, and then when the app becomes active again the value is different.

I save the value:

```
- (void)appDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //Tiempo inicial de inactividad

    NSUserDefaults *dispositivo = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSTimeInterval timestamp = ([[NSDate date]  timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000);

    [dispositivo setFloat:timestamp forKey:@"StartBackground"];

    NSLog(@"Start background: %f", timestamp);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Log: **Start background: 1418731653366.276123**

I want to recover the value:

```
- (void)appDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSUserDefaults *dispositivo = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSTimeInterval startDate = [dispositivo floatForKey:@"StartBackground"];
    NSLog(@"Start date: %f", startDate);
}
```

Log: **Start date: 1418731716608.000000**

This is the only place I use this value.
Thank you for advance.

Comment: You can simply store the NSDate object itself in NSUserDefaults instead of saving it as float.

Comment: You should have to store Double value instead float!

Comment: with double value the result is the same

Comment: Thak you @ZeMoon thats the solution

Answer (score 2):

NSTimeInterval is in double press on it and you will get

```
typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

so you should save value in double not in float

```
[dispositivo setDouble:timestamp forKey:@"StartBackground"];
```

and to get data

```
NSTimeInterval startDate = [dispositivo doubleForKey:@"StartBackground"];
```

its preferable to save `NSDate` object :)

Comment: There is no setDouble method associated with NSUserDefaults

Comment: @ZeMoon you should check please.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing went wrong because you are using [NSDate date]...it will updating the current time...

Comment: I use [NSDate date] to save the date before I enter in background not later. Later I'm reading the value in nsuserdefaluts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013850/whats-the-optimum-way-of-storing-an-nsdate-in-nsuserdefaults...go through this once